# Fill a list/pandas.dataframe with all the missing data combinations (like complete() in R)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, combinations

I have data set like the following (this is an example, it actually has 66k rows):

```
        Type       Food      Loc  Num
0      Fruit     Banana  House-1   15
1      Fruit     Banana  House-2    4
2      Fruit      Apple  House-2    6
3      Fruit      Apple  House-3    8
4  Vegetable   Broccoli  House-3    8
5  Vegetable    Lettuce  House-4   12
6  Vegetable    Peppers  House-5    3
7  Vegetable       Corn  House-4    4
8  Seasoning  Olive Oil  House-6    2
9  Seasoning    Vinegar  House-7    2
```

I'd like to fill all the missing combinations (how many bananas are there in Houses 3-7?, how many peppers are there elsewhere than House-5?) with 0, to get something like:

```
        Type       Food      Loc  Num
0      Fruit     Banana  House-1   15
1      Fruit     Banana  House-2    4
2      Fruit     Banana  House-3    0
... fill remaining houses with zeros
6      Fruit     Banana  House-7    0
7      Fruit      Apple  House-1    0
8      Fruit      Apple  House-2    6
9      Fruit      Apple  House-3    8
... fill remaining houses with zeros
14  Vegetable   Broccoli  House-1    0
15  Vegetable   Broccoli  House-2    0
16  Vegetable   Broccoli  House-3    8
... etc    
n   Seasoning    Vinegar  House-7    2
```

I know that R has the [`complete` function](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/tidyr/man/complete.html) integrated.

Right now I had been working with a list that was digested from the original DataFrame, which I transformed into a dictionary.

```
for key,grp in fruit.groupby(level=0):
        dir[key] = test.ix[key].values.tolist()

fruit = {'Banana': [[1.0,15.0], [2.0,4.0],
         'Apple': [[2.0,6.0], [3.0,8.0]

#Type = {fruit1:[[Loc1,Count1],...,[Locn],[Countn],
#... fruitn:[...]}
```

I designed this function to apply to the assignation rule of the dictionary:

```
def fill_zeros(list):
    final = [0] * 127
    for i in list:
        final[int(i[0])] = i[1]
    return final
```

That works on individual "fruits":

```
print fill_zeros(test.ix['QLLSEEEKK'].values.tolist())
print fill_zeros(test.ix['GAVPLEMLEIALR'].values.tolist())
print fill_zeros(test.ix['VPVNLLNSPDCDVK'].values.tolist())
```

But doesn't on the dictionary:

```
for key,grp in test.groupby(level=0):
        dir[key] = fill_zeros(test.ix[key].values.tolist())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peptidecount.py", line 59, in <module>
    print fill_zeros(test.ix[str(key)].values.tolist())
  File "peptidecount.py", line 43, in fill_zeros
    final[int(i[0])] = i[1]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Apparently I'm not iterating correctly on the dictionary. Is there a way to correct that? Or is there a more suitable function to apply directly on the DataFrame?

Comment: can you post a desired data set? This would help to understand what are you after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

First you'll need a list of the valid `(type, food)` pairs. I'll get it from the data itself, rather than writing them out.

```
In [88]: kinds = list(df[['Type', 'Food']].drop_duplicates().itertuples(index=False))

In [89]: kinds
Out[89]:
[('Fruit', 'Banana'),
 ('Fruit', 'Apple'),
 ('Vegetable', 'Broccoli'),
 ('Vegetable', 'Lettuce'),
 ('Vegetable', 'Peppers'),
 ('Vegetable', 'Corn'),
 ('Seasoning', 'Olive Oil'),
 ('Seasoning', 'Vinegar')]
```

Now we'll generate all the pairs for those `kinds` with the houses using `itertools.product`.

```
In [93]: from itertools import product

In [94]: houses = ['House-%s' % x for x in range(1, 8)]

In [95]: idx = [(x.Type, x.Food, house) for x, house in product(kinds, houses)]

In [96]: idx[:2]
Out[96]: [('Fruit', 'Banana', 'House-1'), ('Fruit', 'Banana', 'House-2')]
```

And now you can use `set_index` and `reindex` to get the missing observations.

```
In [98]: df.set_index(['Type', 'Food', 'Loc']).reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
Out[98]:
                           Num
Type      Food    Loc
Fruit     Banana  House-1   15
                  House-2    4
                  House-3    0
                  House-4    0
                  House-5    0
...                        ...
Seasoning Vinegar House-3    0
                  House-4    0
                  House-5    0
                  House-6    0
                  House-7    2

[56 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Is the full cartesian product the right thing to do?  It seems like it would give extra combinations between `Type` and `Food`.  Ex: `(Fruit, Banana, House-1)`, `(Vegetable, Banana, House-1)`, and `(Seasoning, Banana, House-1)` would all be index values, but only the first seems like it'd be desired.  Instead of the full cartesian product `Type X Food X Loc`, I'm thinking it should be `[Type, Food] X Loc`, if that makes sense. Or maybe I'm just reading too much into the sample data?

Comment: What is k? What are x[0] and x[1]?

Comment: Sorry, `k` was supposed to be `kinds`, but I missed it. `x[0]` and x[1]` are unpacking the tuples from the tuples in kinds. I've edited it to use namedtuples, so hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: This worked almost great! Only (big) problem: every food got duplicated as many times as available data points there were. So for example I have info about house 1 for banana twice (because I have two banana data points). What could be the issue?
EDIT: It's the reindex function :/

Comment: You could probably preprocess those with a groupby, `df.groupby(['Type', 'Food', 'Loc']).Num.sum()`. Or you would need an additional `observation_number` column to track that

Comment: It was my fault! Your code worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Hey! I was using part of your code for a subset of my data base, let's say fruits.

   `test = df.ix['Fruit']` //,
    `houses = ['House-%s' % x for x in range(1, 8)]`//
   `ind = list(set((test.index.values.tolist())))`,//
   `idx = [(x, house)  for x, house in product(ind,houses)]`,//
 `table=test.reset_index().set_index(['Food','House']).reindex(idx,fill_value=0)`

That worked perfectly, but now I want to apply that to the whole data set.

Comment: `ind = (set((df.index.values.tolist())))` //  `idx = [(x, fraction)  for x, house in product(ind,houses)]` 
and then applying the triple index to the original dataframe
`table = df.reset_index().set_index(['Type','Food','House']).reindex(idx    ,fill_value=0)`
gives away this error:
`File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 1422, in reindex
    raise Exception("cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`

Comment: When trying to apply your method for the first part (aka using `kinds = list(df[['Type', 'Food']].drop_duplicates().itertuples(index=False))`) raises the following error:
`raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['Type' 'Food'] not in index"`

Comment: Now I see the problem! idx has this format: [((type,food),house), (...), ... ] and I need them to be at the same level. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
cond0 = df.Num.isnull()
cond1 = df.Food == 'Banana'
cond2 = df.Loc.str.match(r'House-[34567]')
cond3 = df.Food == 'Peppers'
cond4 = df.Loc != 'House-5'

missing_bananas = cond0 & cond1 & cond2
missing_peppers = cond0 & cond3 & cond4
missing_food = missing_bananas | missing_peppers

df.loc[missing_food] = df.loc[missing_food].fillna(0)
```